# summarise_each function in dplyr does not work

Tags: r, dplyr

I have data set including TimeStamp and wind speed :

```
 TimeStamp MeanWindSpeed102.5 MeanWindSpeed100.0 MeanWindSpeed76.6
2 2013-08-27 17:30:00               4.25               4.19              3.94
3 2013-08-27 17:40:00               4.39               4.34              4.16
4 2013-08-27 17:50:00               4.83               4.76              4.29
5 2013-08-27 18:00:00               4.96               4.91              4.22
6 2013-08-27 18:10:00               5.22               5.18              4.47
7 2013-08-27 18:20:00               5.18               5.15              5.01
```

I tried to use dplyr package as follow :

```
a = data %>% 
  dplyr::select(TimeStamp, matches("MeanWindSpeed")) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(m = month(TimeStamp)) %>%
  dplyr::group_by(m) %>%
  dplyr::summarise_each(funs(mean(., na.rm = TRUE)))
```

I'm getting error like :

```
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: could not find function "month".
```

but my TimeStamp format is correct :

```
str(data$TimeStamp)
 POSIXct[1:54459], format: "2013-08-27 17:30:00" "2013-08-27 17:40:00" "2013-08-27 17:50:00" ...
```

and if I just comment that line to proceed like :

```
a = data %>% 
  dplyr::select(TimeStamp, matches("MeanWindSpeed")) %>%
  #dplyr::mutate(m = month(TimeStamp)) %>%
  #dplyr::group_by(m) %>%
  dplyr::summarise_each(funs(mean(., na.rm = TRUE)))
```

the `summerise_each` function does not work as well :

```
`summarise_each()` is deprecated.
Use `summarise_all()`, `summarise_at()` or `summarise_if()` instead.
To map `funs` over all variables, use `summarise_all()`
```

Do I miss something ? Any idea why I'm getting these errors ?

Comment: I think you need to add `library (lubridate)` and use `summarize_at` instead if `summarize_each`

Comment: `summarise_all()` is closer to `summarise_each()` per the warning message. `summarise_at()` will require specificying columns